EVI2 calculation，Issues arising from collection 1 to collection 2
Old code:
var L5_EVI2= function(image) { 
var evi2 = image.expression( '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 2.4 * RED + 1))', 
{ 
'NIR': image.select('B4'), 'RED': image.select('B3') 
} 
).rename('EVI2');
var L5_SR1 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR")
    .filterDate('1986-01-01', '1999-12-31') 
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',30))
    .select(['B3','B4','pixel_qa'])
    .filterBounds(shpMask); 

New code
var L5_EVI2= function(image) { 
var evi2 = image.expression( '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 2.4 * RED + 1))', 
{ 
'NIR': image.select('SR_B4'), 'RED': image.select('SR_B3') 
} 
).rename('EVI2');
var L5_SR1 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2")
    .filterDate('1986-01-01', '1999-12-31') 
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',30))
    .select(['SR_B3','SR_B4','QA_PIXEL'])
    .filterBounds(shpMask); 

Why do I have different EVI2 results calculated for the same region after going from collection 1 to collection 2? I only changed the corresponding band name and dataset name. The other code was not changed.

Your code is incomplete

Please [Edit] the Question to contain an accurate code block. Comments are illegible for this purpose.

I re-edited the question and the code all works fine, the problem is that the results are different, I was just referring to the instructions for migrating from Landsat Acquisition 1 to Acquisition 2.
